# MVC4 Dynamic Menu Generation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, menu

I want to generate menu from database for that I have implemented my logic and its responding well, the issue is that I am unable to render menu from my controller method. I want to ask if its possible to return HTML from action controller method and render it on my view by using **Html.Action("MenuGenerator","Menu")** but I am unable to achieve this. Moreover I donot want to create partial view for menu since my method returns menu as html string and I just want to flush it out to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Html.Action is a basic helper method. All it does is return a MVCHtmlString. You will have to create your own helper extension that returns your custom HTML to build your menu.

Comment: can I add cache to helper method ? I have created action controller method so that I can cache it.